# Word for being interested in an ad

Tags: single-word-requests

So I need a word (or short sentence) for being interested in an ad. Just as for showing interest in a hotel room you'd book it, what would you do if you show interest in an ad? Thanks

Comment: Parallel with your example "would book the room" is "would buy the product".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word for showing interest in an ad is [engagement](https://theonlineadvertisingguide.com/glossary/engagement-rate/).

> Engagement is any interaction with content. For example on a video it would include pausing the video, resizing the screen or changing the volume. It is mainly used as a social media metric, but is also used with traditional online advertising.
>
> Engagement Rate is a relatively new metric which defines how much, given the chance, users are engaging with ads. It is a helpful measure to gauge users interest in ads, as it shows that users have noticed the ad. Although this is a very small win for advertisers, it is a step in building a relationship with a user.

Contrast this with an [ad impression](https://theonlineadvertisingguide.com/glossary/ad-impression/), which just means that the ad content was displayed to the user but does no imply that they were interested. Engagement does not imply that the viewer will actually purchase the product or service, only that they have shown interest in the ad content.